# Expected expression error on accelerometer data

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I am new to Xcode and am trying to use the accelerometer's xyz values. When I was doing this, I got the expected expression error on the last two lines below. Does anyone know what my problem is?

```
self.motionManager = [[CMMotionManager alloc] init];
self.motionManager.accelerometerUpdateInterval = 0.04;

NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init]; 
[self.motionManager start AccelerometerUpdatesToQueue:queue withHandler:^
(CMAccelerometerData *accelerometerData, NSError *error(]; 
**// I got the expected expression error on the two lines above**
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet is to use something like this:

```
    [self.motionManager startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] withHandler:^(CMAccelerometerData *accelerometerData, NSError *error)
//code here
]
```

The problem is that you have

```
[self.motionManager start AccelerometerUpdatesToQueue:queue withHandler:^
(CMAccelerometerData *accelerometerData, NSError *error(];
```

You need to change the (] to ) *insert code here* ]. You also need to insert NSOperationMainQueue.

Comment: This is just a duplicate of @Ewan Mellor's answer, but with less explanatory text.

Answer (score 1):

You need

```
[self.motionManager startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue:queue withHandler:^(CMAccelerometerData *accelerometerData, NSError *error) {
    // Some code here
}];
```

No space between `start` and `Accelerometer`, and close the parens after `NSError` and add the handler content.

And you need to read some Objective C tutorials.